# How to add an external css file to AngularJS without html head tags

Tags: css, angularjs, jsp

Is there anyway to include an external css file to jsp without a head tag? I have only  tags, so I dont know how to add a style sheet to it. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Check if this article is helpful https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/angular-dynamically-injecting-css-file-using-route-resolve-and-promises-7bfcb8ccd05b

Answer (score 1):

```
you can link css as below
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="my-file.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="userCtrl">

<div class="w3-container">

<h3>Users</h3>

<table class="w3-table w3-bordered w3-striped">
  <tr>
    <th>Edit</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
    <td>
      <button class="w3-btn w3-ripple" ng-click="editUser(user.id)">&#9998; Edit</button>
    </td>
    <td>{{ user.fName }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.lName }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<button class="w3-btn w3-green w3-ripple" ng-click="editUser('new')">&#9998; Create New User</button>


</div>

<script src= "myUsers.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```